# Having issues with Django-Graphene

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-django

[image]i built my own content management system here: https://github.com/bastianhilton/Alternate-CMS and I have added graphql support recently with Django-Graphene and updated my models, schema.py. However as I try to run a query, i'm getting the below message. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "relation \"shop_addresscountry\" does not exist\nLINE 1: ... \"shop_addresscountry\".\"is_shipping_country\" FROM \"shop_addr...\n                                                             ^\n"
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "allAddresscountry": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`relation \"shop_addresscountry\" does not exist`
This is a database error, that your database does not have the tables, normally these commands will fix it.

`python manage.py makemigrations`

`python manage.py migrate`

But you should also move your application logic to another app, i.e. views and models. To create a new app simply use code

`python manage.py startapp <app_name>`

app_name like products, orders, customers etc. may be applicable for you.

also refer [this article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/) if you are new to django.